# Join Two Objects for Custom Serialization?

Tags: linq, list, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

In C# on Framework 4, I have a List and List. They can be joined on the JoinId property. ParentObj will have 2 ChildObj matches, sometimes 10.

I would like to take each Parent and all Children and serialize to a single XML entity. I am having a hard time figuring out where to start, because I also need to serialize the objects in a custom way. Can I use Linq-to-XML in this case to get each object written correctly? XmlSerializer? Not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> > Can I use Linq-to-XML in this case to get each object written correctly?

Yes. This is exactly what you need. [A basic example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2007/02/20/xlinq-create-xml-from-object-using-linq.aspx).

> > XmlSerializer?

This will work too, but this approach is older and I think it is less appropriate and more complicated in this case.